# How can I fix not working oh-my-zsh plugins

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I've just discovered oh-my-zsh, but I can't get it to work. While themes work just perfectly, plugins do not. I have some plugins selected, eg. macports, but neither I get port command completion nor do appropriate aliases work. Here's my `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
export ZSH_THEME="steeef"

# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion
# export CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Comment this out to disable weekly auto-update checks
# export DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable colors in ls
# export DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable autosetting terminal title.
# export DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
plugins=(git osx github macports textmate svn)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# Customize to your needs...
export
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

textmate and osx plugins also do not seem to work. `zsh` complains about unknown command and stops. git and svn have some basic completion but I'm not sure whether it's done by plugin or just a normal zsh completion. Do I have to export something to use those plugins? Or if not, what to do to have that fixed?

Comment: how did you conclude they're not working? can you paste zsh errors here?

Comment: the errors are just a normal output like "command not found" when typing command that should be available.

Comment: can you paste the path you ended up using that worked for you? I'm having the same issue and it would be really helpful

Comment: Sorry, it was 2 years ago, I have changed my system and no longer use oh-my-zsh because of poor performance compared to properly configured bash.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got bitten by this.

What happened is you did a manual install *and* the instructions for the manual install don't mention that you need to set the `PATH` yourself.

So you end up with the default PATH.  The source for the automatic setup code copies your current path and appends it to the `.zshrc`, which isn't enough if you depend on non-standard `PATH` entries (e.g. you run Homebrew on a Mac).

So the fix is simple:

Fire up your old shell and its configuration file and then copy and paste the value of `$PATH` into the top of your `~/.zshrc` file.

Ciao!

Comment: Do you know *why* this would cause your plugins not to work (what does zsh need on the path?) I cannot seem to get mine to work (on arch linux).

Answer (score 62):

Make sure that you define your plugins variable before you initialize zsh:

```
plugins=(git wd)
export ZSH=/home/<user>/.oh-my-zsh
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Comment: With me the problem was that: I had plugins bar after ZSH lin:

Comment: for me the solution was to move `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` to the end of .zshrc, after all of my user configs.

Comment: on further investigation the issue looks to be having `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` before setting vi mode on with `bindkey -v` and remapping some zsh shortcuts and some keys in vi mode, otherwise plugins work as normal.
the issue is that if you source after, vi mode stops working. the OMZ plugin in question is fzf.

Comment: I had `#` before `plugins` :D

Comment: In my case it was `export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh` which solved the problem thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem just now! There was a package called `grml-zsh-config` installed in my Archlinux. I removed this package and `oh-my-zsh` themes started to work.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, in `~/.zshrc` I had repeated plugins variable

```
plugins=(git)
.
.
.
plugins=(git autojump zsh-syntax-highlighting zsh-autosuggestions)
```

Check to see if this is the case with you because with this only your git plugin will be used.

Remove the first plugins variable and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try manually source your plugins like this:

`source ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh`

Full `.zshrc` example:

```sh
# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)

plugins=(zsh-autosuggestions)

source ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this with the `kubectl` plugin.

Looking at the contents of `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/kubectl/kubectl.plugin.zsh` I realized I didn't have the same content as what was on the github repo. Manually updating the file with the contents from the [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/kubectl/kubectl.plugin.zsh) repo helped and the plugin started to work. Guess I had to update my oh-my-zsh installation to get the latest plugin content but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I forgot to add custom plugin name to .zshrc file:

```
plugins=(customPluginName)
```

And reload .zshrc:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure the folders of the plugins are located in the ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins folder. I will advise you are on this directory when you git clone the plugins.
Secondly ensure that you seperate the list of plugins in the ~/.zshrc file with a single space NOT comma.

```
.
.
.
plugin = (git zsh-syntax-highlighting)

.
.
.
```

So in the above example, two plugins are added there: git and zsh-syntax-highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

If your `.zshrc` has this at the top

```
export ZSH="~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

try to changing it to:

```
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing the custom plugins manually, moving them to the `$ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/` location solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem,when i writen:

```bash
plugins=(git node)
```

it didn't work

so i installed node again and add path to `PATH`

```bash
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/node@18/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that cli tools/commands referred by plugins are already installed. For example, it will fail if you include kubectl plugin while you didn't install kubectl beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Many of the plugins are dependent on certain binaries existing and will *silently* fail to install if that binary is not found on the $PATH.

Ex: the kubectl plugin requires kubectl to be installed - the plugin script just bails and doesn't even install the aliases if it can't find the command on the $PATH.

This check is at the start of many such plugins

```
if (( ! $+commands[kubectl] )); then
  return
fi
```

Note: This means you need to initialize `brew` before any plugins based on binaries that are installed via `brew` will work.

I found that putting the `brew` plugin at the start of the list seems to work as well as `oh-my-zsh` seems to initialize the plugins in order. Your results may vary.

This works (kubectl aliases are installed):

```
plugins=(brew kubectl)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

This does not work (kubectl aliases are not installed):

```
plugins=(kubectl brew)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```