# How can I enable git-flow-completion in oh-my-zsh?

Tags: git-flow, oh-my-zsh

I'm using [`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) and attempting to enable [`git-flow-completion`](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion). I'm following the instructions [here](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion#installation-for-zsh) to install it as a plugin.

I cloned the plugin files as instructed:

```
git clone https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/git-flow-completion
```

My plugin directory structure looks identical to the example in the installation instructions.

I've edited my `~/.zshrc` file to include:

```
plugins=(git git-flow git-flow-completion)
```

However, git flow completion is not working. When I type `git flow` and hit `tab`, I get a list of files in the current directory instead of the `git flow` subcommands.

The built-in plugins work fine. I edited my `~/.zshrc` to include:

```
plugins=(git git-flow git-flow-completion emoji emoji-clock)
```

When I open a new terminal, the `random_emoji` and `emoji-clock` functions produce the expected output, but git flow completion still does not work.

I've [added my existing PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224188/1023812) to my `.zshrc` above the line that loads `oh-my-zsh.sh`. No luck.

I've [checked the value of `$ZSH_CUSTOM`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Customization) and it is pointing to the directory where the `git-flow-completion` plugin is installed.

I wanted to know if custom plugins were being loaded at all, so I installed [this auto-stats plugin](https://gist.github.com/oshybystyi/475ee7768efc03727f21) and it worked correctly, so this problem seems to be isolated to the `git-flow-completion` plugin.

I've also tried loading the plugin file directly:

```
source ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/git-flow-completion/git-flow-completion.zsh
```

There was no output from this command, and completion still does not work.

How can I go about troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 11):

This was a nasty problem ... but I got it fixed.

First remove these two file:

```
rm /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
rm /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-flow-completion.bash
```

Then reset the [completion cache](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-reset-the-completion-cache):

```
# Delete the completion cache
rm "$ZSH_COMPDUMP"
# Restart the zsh session
exec zsh
```

Comment: Found the reference to this solution on https://nickdenardis.com/2020/10/25/git-flow-completion-with-oh-my-zsh-on-macos/ He/She explains very well the problem and the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and no amount of updating helped. What did the trick in the end was commenting the default git completion (found in `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh`) with the one found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Completion/Unix/Command/_git). I basically followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion#installation-for-zsh).

EDIT: I would like to point out that this "fix" has broken my git completion for `git push -u origin [BRANCH]` as it now completes from `git push -u or` to

```
git push -u or__git_remote_repositories:4: command not found _ssh_hosts
igin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rm /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-flow-completion.bash
```

It works for me.